# Restlet, CLAP, Ajax, and chunk timeouts

Tags: java, ajax, json, restlet, chunked-encoding

We're using RESTlet to do a small little REST server for a project we have. We set up a bunch of routes in a class inheriting from `Application`:

```
public static void createRestServer(ApplicationContext appCtx, String propertiesPath) throws Exception {

  // Create a component
  Component component = new Component();
  component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8081);
  component.getClients().add(Protocol.FILE);
  component.getClients().add(Protocol.CLAP);

  Context context = component.getContext().createChildContext();
  RestServer application = new RestServer(context);

  application.getContext().getParameters().add("useForwardedForHeader", "true");

  application.getContext().getAttributes().put("appCtx", appCtx);
  application.getContext().getAttributes().put("file", propertiesPath);

  // Attach the application to the component and start it
  component.getDefaultHost().attach(application);
  component.start();
}

private RestServer(Context context) {
  super(context);
}

public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {
  Router router = new Router(getContext());

  // we then have a bunch of these
  router.attach("/accounts/{accountId}", AccountFetcher.class); //LIST Account level
  // blah blah blah

  // finally some stuff for static files:
  //
  Directory directory = new Directory(getContext(),
     LocalReference.createClapReference(LocalReference.CLAP_CLASS, "/"));
  directory.setIndexName("index.html");
  router.attach("/", directory);

  return router;
}
```

The problem: If I request a *.js* file in the JAR via Ajax from a web page (also loaded via CLAP from this JAR), it'll only return the first 7737 bytes of that file and then hang. I can't get it to return the rest of the file.  It always hangs after exactly the same number of bytes.  1 in 50 times it works.

Any ideas why it's hanging?  Can I just turn off chunked encoding for CLAP and static files (all ours are quite small).

This is driving us nuts.

Comment: Can you indicate which version of Restlet you are using. Did you try with latest 2.2 version (stable)?

Comment: Are you connecting directly to the container (Jetty, Tomcat, ...) or is there something in between - like an Apache HTTP Server? We had the problem that this one closed the connection after 8kb of data.

Comment: GIve complete details of you deployment including JDK version, Servlet Engine Version ?

Comment: Sounds to me a timeout issue. I would increase the timeout value both on the client and server.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a better answer, but we effectively abandoned this framework because of this and other annoyances that were driving us nuts. I suppose w some more persistence the issue could have been found, but it was a minor secondary project, so …

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which server connector you use for your application but it seems that it's the default one.

Restlet is pluggable and extensible at different levels. I recommend you to use the Jetty one. To do that simply add the JAR file for the Jetty extension (`org.restlet.ext.jetty.jar`) within your classpath. The connector will be automatically registered and use instead of the default one.

I also recommend you to upgrade to the latest version (2.3).

To see which connectors are registered in the Restlet engine, you can use the following code:

```
List<ConnectorHelper<Server>> serverConnectors
       = Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredServers();
for (ConnectorHelper<Server> connectorHelper : serverConnectors) {
    System.out.println("Server connector: "+connectorHelper);
}
```

You shouldn't have such problems after doing this.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry